# Why is this function returning the error value when modified for this cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a set of raw data (see Raw_Tab.png) on one tab of my Excel sheet, and I have the organized data (see Organized_Tab.png) in another tab. Everything works perfectly when written/implemented throughout Row 2 of the Organized tab, as you can see.

However, when I copy the same formula to any other rows, and change $A2 to $A3 etc. as I move down my rows, the formula just returns the error value of 0. But as you can see in the Raw_Tab.png image, there is in fact a plot_id of 2, with a class of 1, and a metric of area_mn, and it does have a corresponding value that should be pulled into the organized table. Can anybody help clarify what I'm missing with my formula?

Raw Data Tab:
[image: Raw Data Tab]

Organized Data Tab:
[image: Organized Data Tab]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the MATCH function this way, with multiple conditions in the *lookup_array* parameter, the *lookup_value* must always be set to 1. The correct formula should be:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(RawData[value], MATCH(1, (RawData[plot_id]=$A3)*(RawData[class]=1)*(RawData[metric]="area_mn"), 0)), 0)
```

The first row just happened to work for you because the value in cell A2 was, in fact, 1.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! I spent so long trying to figure out what I was missing and couldn't wrap my head around it. Crazy how that little thing was breaking the whole formula. No telling how much longer it would've taken me to realize. Again, thank you so much for your help and clarification!